# Como verificar se uma data já está no formato correto em php?

Tags: php, mysql, formatação

Estou pegando uma data em formulário e no firefox o campo DATE se comporta como um campo de texto normal. Ai, caso a pessoa digite um data no formato `dd/mm/yyyy`, tenho uma função que converte essa data pra salvar no MariaDB(MySql).O problema é que no chrome a data já vem formatada,ai nao precisa dessa formatação!

O que eu quero é fazer a verificação pra ver se esta data já no formato certo, pois se estiver quero ignorar a formatação.

segue a função:

```
function traduz_data_para_banco($parametro){

    if($parametro === null){
        echo "data nula"; 
        return;
    }
    $data_picada = explode("/",$parametro);
    $data_USA = "{$data_picada[2]}" . "-" . "{$data_picada[1]}" . "-" . "{$data_picada[0]}";

    return $data_USA;

}
```

Comment: Pq não explicar em formato brasileiro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor forma de validar datas no PHP é utilizando a classe [DateTime()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php).

Acredito que o mais importante não seja verificar se a data já vem no formato americano, mas se o usuário está informando a data corretamente

```
$data = '10/08/2017';
echo validarData($data, 'd/m/Y');

echo PHP_EOL; // Apenas quebra alinha

$data = '2017/08/10';
echo validarData($data, 'Y/m/d');

function validarData($date, $format = 'Y-m-d') {

    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);

    if ($d && $d->format($format) != $date) {
        echo 'Data Inválida';
    }

    return $d->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

E recomendo sempre usar a função para validar data, mesmo que o *chrome* retorne a data no formato banco, pois se um dia isso mudar, seu sistema já estará preparado para esta alteração.

Answer (score 0):

$data = explode('/', $vigenciac);
                if (!checkdate($data[1], $data[0], $data[2])):
                    $mensagem .= '

Formato da Data do início da vigência inválido.

';
                endif;

eu utilizo essa função e funciona perfeitamente para entrada de data.